# C# ASPX Errors - "'Sys' Is Not Defined" - Caused by "GET https://domain/ScriptResource.axd? 404 (Not Found)"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ajax, webmethod

I have a asp:ScriptManager loading a javascript file which handles some WebMethods so I can dynamically update data in my website. The site works locally for me but when I put it on a different server, it loads with the error in the title and the JS doesn't work. This is the final line in my javascript which returns the errors:

```
if (typeof(Sys) !== "undefined") Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
```

This appears to be a pretty wide spread error with what seems like a million solutions, none that have seemed to work thus far for me.

I have a feeling that it's not loading the AJAX files properly or at all.

One trick I was reading about was to locally include the 2 AJAX .dll files (System.Web.Extensions.dll & System.Web.Extensions.Design.dll) in a bin folder but I don't know how to include these in the web.config or Default.aspx files rather than whatever it is trying to access and failing.

Does anyone have a fix to this that doesn't include editing the properties of the IIS site as I don't have access to do so?

Below is my Script Manager reference at the bottom of my page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" 
  id="ScriptManager1"
  EnablePageMethods="true">
    <scripts>
      <asp:ScriptReference Path="js/scripts.js"></asp:ScriptReference>
    </scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Thankyou in advance,
Matt.

Edit: added ScriptManager reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem that putting the entire site in the parent directory as opposed to a sub-folder within the parent directory fixed it. Originally I was using the sub-folder for test purposes.

Comment: If you're using a version of .NET prior to 4.0, the web.config contains a handler mapping for ScriptResource.axd. If that web.config were in a sub-folder, then it wouldn't be able to apply to the top level for requests to ~/ScriptResource.axd and it would 404. You could retain a sub-folder testing setup by adding the ASP.NET AJAX bits of your sub-folder's web.config into the site root's web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the scriptmanager at the top of the page.

Comment: No I never. It was a genuine suggestion. I've had issues with ScriptManagers and their location in pages

Comment: Heh, big apologies then mate, just very similar to the first post. Thanks for the tip :)